# UITableView Cells Disappear after Dismiss View That I Add

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm having a difficult time understanding what I should even be looking for to debug this issue.

I have a UITableView that populates correctly.

I select one of the UITableViewCells which upon selection presents a new view to the user with more detail.

If I click Back on this new window, the original UITableView shows none of the UITableViewCells anymore.

[image]

Comment: sounds like your tableview is being populated with an empty array.  Put a breakpoint somewhere inside `cellForRowAt` and see if the same data is being passed in or if it's being called again (which it shouldn't).  Also check `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: @luke, if he is using a push segue, the table and data shouldn't unload and he doesn't need to manage it. Stephen, What kind of function are you using to display the new window? also where is the data you are using to populate your table coming from? could you perhaps add a piece of your code for us to be able to help you!

Comment: Check your `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` methods to make sure you are not resetting your data source. Post these methods and the 2 methods mentioned by @luke if you are having trouble stepping through your code with the debugger.

Comment: @PauloMattos I used Balsamiq Mockups.

Comment: @luke I'm doing everything programmatically without IB. I'm just doing a self.present(...)

Comment: @Stephen do you hit a breakpoint inside `cellForRowAt` or `numberOfRowsInSection` once you go back to the previous view controller where the tableview is populated?

Comment: @luke I do. The data source is empty.

Comment: @Stephen you shouldn't. Are you overriding methods `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`at all? If so post them. Also post your calling  `self.present(...)`

Comment: @luke ok give me 10m

Comment: @Stephen can you please share your code, so we can help you.

Comment: @luke ok, so I figured out the issue. I needed to set the delegate and datasource in the viewDidAppear rather than the viewDidLoad. Once I did that, I added a tableView.reloadData() inside of the completion handler for retrieving the data from the API.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is when you are coming back, your array is being empty somehow. In your first "ViewController" override the "viewWillAppear()" method and print the count of your array in this method. Then load the app and check the print result, then go to second "ViewController" and press the back button and see the print results again. if it shows zero "0" then check your code and try to find out where your array is being empty.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the delegate and datasource in the viewDidAppear() rather than the viewDidLoad(). Once I did that, I added a tableView.reloadData() inside of the completion handler for retrieving the data from the API and the tableView was then being populated as expected.